# Check two float/double values for exact equality

Tags: java, floating-point

What is an elegant, readable and non-verbose way of comparing two floating point value for exact equality?

As simple as it may sound, its a wicked problem. The `==` operator doesn't get the job done for NaN and also has special treatment for zero:

```
(+0.0 == -0.0) -> true
Double.NaN == Double.NaN -> false
```

But I want to determine if two values are exactly the same (but I do *not* care for different NaN patterns, so any NaN == any other NaN -> true).

I *can* do this with this ugly Monster piece of code:

```
Double.doubleToLongBits(a) == Double.doubleToLongBits(b)
```

Is there a better way to write this (and make the intent obvious)?

Comment: You don't day why you want to do this. If they really are floating point numbers your answer won't be meaningful.

Comment: @Julian See PeterLawrey's answer for one example where it is very meaningful. My application however is the equals() method of an object where a float is part of the primary key (not by my choice). Floating point usually defies intuitive assumptions, so I am careful to have the edge cases covered.

Comment: Sorry, you could not do it better, your "ugly Monster piece" is already perfect...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you've got is already the best way of doing it, I'd say. It makes it clear that you're interested in the *bitwise* representation of the value. You happen to be converting those bits to `long` as a convenient 64-bit type which doesn't have any funky behaviour.

If you don't want it appearing frequently in your codebase, just add a method to wrap it:

```
public static boolean bitwiseEqualsWithCanonicalNaN(double x, double y) {
    return Double.doubleToLongBits(x) == Double.doubleToLongBits(y);
}
```

Note that as per your question, this does *not* differentiate between different NaN values. If you wanted to do this at a later date, you'd need to use [`Double.toRawLongBits`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29).

Comment: Mhhh, both your and Peter's answer have their appeal. For the sake of clarity I think the static helper is a little better, since I can just put my comment on the method and anyone stumbling over the call(s) will arrive there. Still thinking about a good method name though.

Answer (score 23):

You can use

```
Double.compare(a, b) == 0
```

From the javadoc for compareTo

- Double.NaN is considered by this method to be equal to itself and greater than all other double values (including Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY).
- 0.0d is considered by this method to be greater than -0.0d.

Comment: Will that differentiate between the two 0s properly too?

Comment: It will do NaNs. Checking for -0 and 0

Comment: I've just checked. It does. Nice - although not *obviously* correct, I'd say. (I would intuitively have *expected* that to claim that positive and negative zero are equal. I prefer the code which makes it stonkingly obvious that you're interested in the precise bits.)

Comment: @Jon: Just as obvious as the collapsing of different `NaN` values to a single canonical value made by `doubleToLongBits`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Yes, I agree that's not very obvious :) I've edited my answer to have a more specific wrapper method name.

Comment: Very clever, would never have guessed that a seemingly simple compare method would contain such elaborate logic. Thinking about it ... the behavior is pretty much what I would want to have when using it for ordering double values (after stumbling over the edge cases :).

Comment: @Durandal, `Double.comapre` uses `doubleToLongBits` internally. I am not sure why you'd care about different NaN values, usually they dont occur naturally (but it might depend on the architecture)

Comment: @JonSkeet, to me: `Double.compare` is the most intuitive one. It must discern between neg/pos (virtually everything), otherwise stuff like TreeMap won't work correctly - but I might be biased.