# JAVA - Comparing a Double value with Float.MIN_VALUE or Integer.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java, double

I have the following issue.

I have some data stored in memory (coming from a database query) by using a hash table:

```
Map<String,MyObject>
```

where MyObject consists of 3 arrays: float[], int[] and double[].
I use Float.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE and Double.MIN_VALUE to store values having a NULL value in the database.

I need to process the input hash table and store the output in a hash table

```
Map<String, Double> output
```

which must contain only NON NULL values.

So, I perform a comparison like this:

```
Double value = ... (get a value from MyObject)
if(value != Float.MIN_VALUE && value != Double.MIN_VALUE && value != Integer.MIN_VALUE){
    // add to OUTPUT hash table
```

but the if statement doesn't work properly when value equals to Float.MIN_VALUE: the first component always returns TRUE (meaning the two values are different).

I also tried something like that

```
if(value != new Double(Float.MIN_VALUE))
```

but the problem is still there.

Anyone could suggest me a solution to properly compare the values?

---

EDIT: Is it safe to use something like that:

```
String.valueOf(value).equals(String.valueOf(Float.MIN_VALUE))) ?
```

It seems to work.

Comment: Float-point arithmetic is inherently in general and especially so when data type  conversions are involved. See all answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572700/check-two-float-double-values-for-exact-equality

Comment: Why don't you use `null` to represent `NULL`?

Comment: If an exact equality test against Float.MIN_VALUE is sufficient for you, try comparing *before* you convert to a Double.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the static methods the double class is offering:

```
Double.isFinite(value);
Double.isInfinite(value);
Double.isNaN(value);
Double.compare(value, Double.MIN_VALUE)
```

Comment: need to use Double.compare(value, Double.MIN_VALUE)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I need to also compare value with Float.MIN_VALUE and my problem is here. value is a DOUBLE, but it has to be compared with 3 MIN_VALUE: Integer, FLoat and Double

Answer (score 0):

This post ist 9 months old, but my response may help other users having to do with doubles and floats.
Fab I don't know how you get a float/double/int value from your Object, but as you kann check it [here](https://ideone.com/ZQR1YF): If an Object gets the **Float.MIN_VALUE** assigned,  its value gotten again as float or as double will surely match **Float.MIN_VALUE**:

```
Object obj =  Float.MIN_VALUE; //1.40129846432481707E-45;
float floatVal = ((Number) obj).floatValue();

System.out.println("obj is a " + obj.getClass().getSimpleName()); // obj is a Float 
boolean result  = floatVal == Float.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.printf("%.60f == %.60f: %s.\n" , floatVal, Float.MIN_VALUE, result ); // true
```

Even if we assign the value gotten from the object to a variable declared as double, the match still holds true:

```
    double doubleVal = ((Number) obj).doubleValue();
    result  = doubleVal == Float.MIN_VALUE;
    System.out.printf("%.60f == %.60f: %s.\n" , doubleVal, Float.MIN_VALUE, result ); //true
```

If we assign the value of **Float.MIN_VALUE** not explicitly as a Float:

```
obj =  Float.MIN_VALUE; //1.40129846432481707E-45;
```

The macths till holds, even though the value of obj is interpreted as a Double:

```
floatVal = ((Number) obj).floatValue();
doubleVal = ((Number) obj).doubleValue();
Formatter fmt = new Formatter(); 

System.out.println("obj is a " + obj.getClass().getSimpleName()); // obj is a Double
result  = floatVal == Float.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.println(fmt.format("%18.17e", floatVal) + " == " + fmt.format("%18.17e", Float.MIN_VALUE) + "? " + result ); // true
result  = doubleVal == Float.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.println(fmt.format("%18.17e", doubleVal) + "= = " + fmt.format("%18.17e",Float.MIN_VALUE) + "? " + result ); // true
```

I hope this will help someone!